# I Want to add the numbers in the matrix

Tags: c

I want the sum of the numbers in the matrix in each column to add up, tried doing this using different variation's of the same music[i+1][j]+=music[i][j], but its not working, so basically what the program does, it assigns 3 points to the first number the user inputs as his favorite song, the second song get 2 points and the third 1 point, i want the matrix at the end to sum up all the points from the participants and give me the total.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{   int num=0, pers=0;

    int i,j, k;

    int votos=0;

    printf("Digite la cantidad de personas:");

    scanf("%d", &pers);

    float music[pers+1][10];

    for(i=0;i<pers+1;i++){

       for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        music[i][j]=0;
       }
    }

for(i=0;i<pers;i++){

  printf("Participante %d :\n",i+1);

       for(k=1;k<=3;k++){

         printf("Digite el numero de sus 3 canciones favoritas %d:\n",k);

          scanf("%d",&num);

           for(j=0;j<9;j++){
             if (k==1){
              music[i][num-1]=3;
            }
               if (k==2){
                music[i][num-1]=2;
              }
               if (k==3){

                music[i][num-1]=1;
              }

               music[10][j]+=music[i][j];
       }
    }
}
    for(i=0;i<pers+1;i++){
       for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf("%.2f\t",music[i][j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }
        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: For programs that accept input, any claims about "not working" should be supported by providing the exact input you gave it, the exact output you got, and a description of how this differs from the output you expected.

Comment: I highly recommend using a debugger like `gdb` to help you solve a few issues with your code here (e.g. using `music[10]` when what I assume you mean is `music[pers]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDB is your friend for these sorts of problems. You can install an interactive debugger and step through your code line by line to see what values your matrix takes on certain input.

If you did that, you may have saw that you're accessing the 10th row of your matrix. Even if `pers` is initialized to three.

There's also an issue where you begin summing music values as they're being initialized (leading to over counting).

```c
  for (i = 0; i < pers; i++)
  {
    printf("Participante %d :\n", i + 1);
    for (k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
    {
      printf("Digite el numero de sus 3 canciones favoritas %d:\n", k);
      scanf("%d", &num);
      if (k == 1)
      {
        music[i][num - 1] = 3;
      }
      if (k == 2)
      {
        music[i][num - 1] = 2;
      }
      if (k == 3)
      {
        music[i][num - 1] = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  for(j = 0 ; j < 10; j++)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < pers+1; i++)
        music[pers][j] += music[i][j];
  }
```

I'm hoping this code doesn't fully solve your problem since it'll be good for you to look into gdb and learn how to interact with your code and understand where its deviating from your expectations.

It'll also help to do as paddy suggested and explain what your input and output is supposed to look like.

Comment: Thank dude, i used the debugger to see what was wrong and i was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code It working and sum up[image: Result]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){ 
int num=0, pers=0;

int i,j, k;

int votos=0;

printf("Digite la cantidad de personas:");

scanf("%d", &pers);

float music[100][100];
float sum[100][100];

for(i=0;i<pers+1;i++){

   for(j=0;j<10;j++){
    music[i][j]=0;
   }
}

for(i=0;i<pers;i++){

printf("Participante %d :\n",i+1);

   for(k=1;k<=3;k++){

     printf("Digite el numero de sus 3 canciones favoritas %d:\n",k);

      scanf("%d",&num);

       for(j=0;j<9;j++){
         if (k==1){
          music[i][num-1]=3;
        }
           if (k==2){
            music[i][num-1]=2;
          }
           if (k==3){

            music[i][num-1]=1;
          }

           sum[i][j]+=music[i][j];
       }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<pers+1;i++){
   for(j=0;j<10;j++){
    printf("%.2f\t",sum[i][j]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `sum` isn't initialized, no telling what you'll get when you do `sum[i][j] += ... `

Comment: @yano Its some the all Index Value Those participant enter